# Getting this error while Get Method : 'API resolved without sending a response for /api/users, this may result in stalled requests.'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am trying to create API with Next-Js. I have also used MongoDB for the database.
Now the problem is when i'm trying to save the users by post method its work fine but when i'm trying to use the get method it is giving me this error: **API resolved without sending a response for /api/users, this may result in stalled requests.**

I have created a users folder inside the api in NextJs.

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');


async function main() {
    const uri = "mongodb+srv://rootuser:<password>@cluster0.ar0xs.mongodb.net/tablecrudDb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
    
    return client;

}

async function createUser(newListing){
    const client = await main();

    try{
        await client.connect();
        const result = await client.db("tablecrudDb").collection("Users").insertOne(newListing);
        console.log(`New listing created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
    
}

async function pullUser(){
    const client = await main();
    console.log('hi iam inside pull user');

    try{
        await client.connect();
        const result = await client.db("tablecrudDb").collection("Users").find({});
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close()
    }

}

//API ROUTES FOR HANDLING USER DATA
export default function handler(req, res) {
      console.log("inside handler");
      const method = req.method;

      switch (method) {
            case 'GET': {
                console.log('inside get switch');
                const getData = async () => {
                    console.log('inside getData');
                    const data = await pullUser();
                    return res.status(200).json({data}).end()
                }
                getData()
                break;
            }
 
            case 'POST': {
                const sendData = async () => {
                    const data = req.body;
                    await createUser(data).catch(console.error);
                    res.status(200).json({user: req.body}).end();
                }
                sendData()
                break;
            }

            default:
              res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} is not allowed`)
              break;
        }
      
}
```

Also to connect the MongoDB i have used this blog: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/node-crud-tutorial/

Also in the uri i have replaced the password ...

Comment: Hi also when i'm placing .findone() instead of .find({}) then also the request is getting the data but in the console i'm getting the same message.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by just adding .toArray() after the .find()....